# What is the best way to accommodate for different screen sizes in a game?

Tags: java, graphics

I am creating a Java game for Windows and I have come across a problem: there are lots of different screens and resolutions when it comes to Windows. What would be the best way to make it so that it looks just about the same on all screens?

Comment: Make the size of the application window fixed.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716302/dealing-with-different-resolutions-for-pixel-based-android-game

Comment: Require that all users use a 666x666 screen size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You basically have three options:

1. **Fix the size of the game window** to something small that will fit n all screens (800*600 maybe)? This is easy to do, but could annoy users with big screens.....
2. Make the game **resolution-independent**, so that that it is rendered to a scale to fit the current window size. This is how most FPS games work for example. The main downside of this is that you need to do some extra scaling maths in your code and there may be some runtime overhead for rescaling images etc.
3. Make the game screen **dynamically resizable**, so that the components within it rearrange and resize themselves to fit the available space (like with a web page). This is the hardest to implement as you have to make use of appropriate layout managers and test lots of different combinations, but can give the nicest user "experience". I've successfully used [MigLayout](http://www.miglayout.com/) to do this in the past with a Swing game.

Any of these options could be best for you depending on the circumstances. It will probably depend mainly on the type/design of your game and your willingness to spend time on making the more complicated methods work well.

Comment: In case of 2. having different sets of images for each resolution range would stop most of the overhead, and the images would have always a good quality (scaling can make them blurry).